# How to change the state of a class using validation using CSS

Tags: html, css, validation

I am creating a form and for each of the form fields, if the user satisfies the validation check (I.e., entering something in the field, making a choice in a drop down, checking off a checkbox, etc)the class of "required" shouldn't be applied to that field any longer. Currently the CSS is set up to to check for validation.

Is there a simple way to do this?

```
#myForm {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 5px;   
    width: 600px;
}

label {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#comments {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
}

.myDropdown {
    width: 250px;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 250px;
}


.centered {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

label.required {
    color: red;
}

select.required,
input[type=text].required {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

input[type=radio].required {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.message {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;    
    width: 600px;
}

.alertMessage {
    color: red;
}

.successMessage {
    color: green;   
}




<?php
    include_once 'includes/error_reporting.php';
    require_once 'includes/form_validation.php';
    include 'includes/function_library.php';



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Royal Caribbean Contest Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/02-27-2017_form.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="myForm">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        <label for="firstName">Enter your first name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" required value="<?php echo $firstName; ?>">

        <br><br>

        <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" required value="<?php echo $lastName; ?>">

        <br><br>

        <label for="city">City:</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" required value="<?php echo $city; ?>">

        <br><br>

        <label for="state">State:</label>
        <select id="state" name="state" required>
            <option value="">Please select a state...</option>
            <?php 
            getStates($satesArray)


            ?>
        </select>

        <br><br>

        <label for="preferredDestination">Preferred destination:</label>
        <select id="preferredDestination" name="preferredDestination" class="myDropdown">
            <option value="">Please select a destination...</option>
                <?php 
                    //asort($Destinationarray);// orginases states
                    getDestinations($Destinationarray);

            ?>
        </select>


        <br><br>

        <label for="preferredDestination">Comments:</label>
        <textarea id="comments" name="comments"><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea>

        <br><br>

        <label for="emailList">Do you want to be included in our e-mail list?</label>
        <input type="radio" value="yes" name="emailList" required>Yes
        <input type="radio" value="no" name="emailList" required>No

        <br><br>

        <div class="centered">
            <input type="checkbox" required name="terms" <?php if ($terms) { echo 'checked'; } ?>>I agree with the terms of this contest
        </div>

        <br><br>

        <div class="centered">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit entry">
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: plz add your `HTML` code as well

Comment: It's hard to say, because you posted only CSS and not working example. Also, for such questions, i.e. when you have some working code, but want to make refactoring of it, you could try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the HTML attribute `required` on your input fields, and then use the `:valid/:invalid` pseudo-class in CSS to change your styles.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:valid

Answer (score -1):

Check out this example on w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Also see this CSS selector https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_required.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
input:required {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3>A demonstration of the :required selector.</h3>

<p>An optional input element:<br><input></p>

<p>A required input element:<br><input required></p>

<p>The :required selector selects form elements with a "required" attribute.</p>

<p>The :required selector is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 or earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: understand the question first before throwing an answer

Comment: If i am understanding this correctly, would removing the class form CSS and add "required" to the end of the  input fields?

Comment: @Kirtar Yes in your HTML add `required` to your input field, then in your CSS use the selector `:required` with `input` like this `input:required` and then choose what you want to display for required fields